Can multiple candidate blocks be mined concurrently by the miner, even if at the end only one block gets added to the chain every 10 mins?
I read that every 10 minutes, the miner would fetch txs from the tx_mempool, process them, create a candidate block, do the proof of work and then broadcast it to the network.
Does this mean that the next batch of txs will be fetched once after 10 mins?
Or can multiple candidate blocks be processed by the miner concurrently so it keeps fetching from the tx_pool?
Even if we do mine multiple blocks within the 10 min window, if only one is going to get selected by the network then a lot of computation has been wasted for nothing.

The two other questions were split off to:

If multiple nodes start at different points, so do we need to sync the nodes so that they are operating at the same time
When exactly does the miner get their reward?



...can the multiple candidate blocks be processed by the miner
concurrently so it keeps fetching from the tx_pool?

Yes anyone is free to construct and perform work on blocks with transactions as they see fit.

...does this mean the ledger of each individual node gets updated 10
mins?

Yes, well the UTXO set, approximately every 10 minutes.

When do i get my reward? When A's chain accepts my block as the most
recent one?

The reward can only be spent after the block reaches a depth of >100.

Well if multiple blocks are being mined but only one gets selected; the work put in the others would be wasted. So what is the incentive to do that?

@Geek same as the incentive to enter a lottery... the chance of winning

ok got it. Can u explain a bit more about the 10 min being avg ; because since target for any node is adjusted every 2016 blocks this means that before the next adjustment there could be many blocks which got added much sooner than 10 mins. Can this be a security concern because if another malicious actor has a higher hash rate they could just overwhelm me with their blocks ?
And is the target adjusted by observing the timestamp of the received blocks after every 2016th block?


Can multiple candidate blocks be mined concurrently by the miner, even if at the end only one block gets added to the chain every 10 mins?

Yes.
And the 10 minute thing is an average. The interval between two successive blocks might easily be 3 seconds or 3 hours.

Miners continuously work on finding new blocks and update block templates whenever they see fit. A new block is found when a block header surpasses the current difficulty requirement. The successful miner publishes the block as soon as they find it, other nodes validate and relay the block, and miners update their block templates to build on top of the new best chaintip.
Because every single attempt at finding a new block has a minuscule chance of succeeding, blocks come in randomly. Sometimes multiple blocks are found within one minute, sometimes it takes over an hour for a new block to be found, but miners are always working on finding the next block and the expected time until the next block is always ten minutes away.
